# fs.readFile is very slow, am I making too many request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, readfile

*node.js beginner here:*

A node.js applications scrapes an array of links (linkArray) from a list of ~30 urls.

Each domain/url has a corresponding (name).json file that is used to check whether the scraped links are new or not.

All pages are fetched, links are scraped into arrays, and then passed to:

```
function checkLinks(linkArray, name){
    console.log(name, "checkLinks");
    fs.readFile('json/'+name+'.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data){
        if(err && err.errno != -4058) throw err;
        if(err && err.errno == -4058){
            console.log(name+'.json', " is NEW .json");
            compareAndAdd(linkArray, {linkArray: []}.linkArray, name);
        }
        else{
            //file EXISTS
            compareAndAdd(linkArray, JSON.parse(data).linkArray, name);
        }
    });
}
```

compareAndAdd() reads:

```
function compareAndAdd(arrNew, arrOld, name){   
    console.log(name, "compareAndAdd()");
    if(!arrOld) var arrOld = [];
    if(!arrNew) var arrNew = [];
    
    //compare and remove dups
    function hasDup(value) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrOld.length; i++)     
            if(value.href == arrOld[i].href)
                if(value.text.length <= arrOld[i].text.length) return false;
            arrOld.push(value);
            return true;
    }
    var rArr = arrNew.filter(hasDup);

    //update existing array;
    if(rArr.length > 0){
        fs.writeFile('json/'+name+'.json', JSON.stringify({linkArray: arrOld}), function (err) {
            if (err) return console.log(err);
            console.log("  "+name+'.json UPDATED');
        });    
    }
    else console.log("  "+name, "no changes, nothing to update");
    return;
}
```

checkLinks() is where the program hangs, it's *unbelievably* slow. I understand that fs.readFile is being hit multiple times a second, but imo less than 30 hits seems pretty trivial: assuming this is a function meant to be used to serve data to (potentially) millions of users. Am I expecting too much from fs.readFile, or (more likely) is there another component (like writeFile, or something else entirely) that's locking everything up.

*supplemental*:

using write/readFileSync creates a lot of problems: this program is inherently async because it begins with request to external websites with largely varied response times and read/write would frequently collide. the functions above insure that writing for a given file only happens after it's been read. (though it is very slow)

Also, this program does not exit on its own, and I do not know why.

### edit

I've reworked the program to read first then write synchronously last and the process is down to ~12 seconds. Apparently fs.readFile was getting hung when called multiple times. I don't understand when/how to use asynchronous fs, if multiple calls hangs the function.

Comment: FYI, doing `throw err` inside an async callback will not be doing you any good as there is no way to catch that throw.

Comment: You need to time each `fs.readFile()` in some `console.log()` and see if they are all slow or only the later ones are slow because the thread pool is busy and thus you are waiting.  I'd suggest outputting exactly how long every one of your `fs.readFile()` operations takes.  Same with `fs.writeFile()`.  We need to see if this is just a thread pool contention issue or if your reads/writes are actually slow for some reason.

Comment: Also, when you say "unbelievably slow", how much time are we talking about?

Comment: @jfriend00 >4 minutes.

Comment: How large are these files?  Are the first few reads and writes a ton faster?

Comment: @jfriend00 each read/write function ends by being passed off to the next function which declares itself. fs.write (compareAndAdd) is nearly instantaneous, while the time between the beginning of checkLinks() and compareAndAdd() is 4 or more minutes, and the only operation between those two functions is the fs.read.

Comment: @jfriend00 these files are between 1 and 6 KB the largest having about 50 entries/array items. the logic (filter comparison) is handled in a fraction of a second.

Comment: Well, something is definitely wrong because I just wrote a test program that can read 100 JSON files from disk, parse them, modify them, convert them back to JSON and write them back to disk and the entire operation takes 253ms from start to finish.  Stock node.js v6.9.2.

Comment: FYI, rather than doing a slow manual search through your array of links, you may want to use a `Set` to keep track of which ones you've already processed.  I doubt that is entirely responsible for this slowness though.

Comment: How many CPUs do you have in the computer you're running this on?

Comment: @jfriend00 v6.9.5, 64x install on a pretty standard desktop, no CPU throttling. I guess if there aren't any glaring faults with the code I should start testing it on other machines- maybe it's a hardware issue. thanks. feel free to check run it yourself, yrmv: https://github.com/SamSlate/linkscraper2json2reddit

Comment: @jfriend00 can I see the code you used to read/write json so quickly?

Comment: Here's the node.js code I used: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rwhe1kcg/.  In the code you posted a link to, I see that you're also doing an http request, then parsing the DOM, then fetching links out of that.  That's more than you showed in question and more than I had in my test app.  My app focused only on the file reading/writing.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks. I'll test this out. parsing in the DOM happens in about <200 ms, i've clocked it out and fs.read is the slow bit.

Answer (score 3):

All async `fs` operations are executed inside the libuv thread pool, which has a default size of 4 (can be changed by setting the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` environment variable to something different). If all threads in the thread pool are busy, any `fs` operations will be queued up.

I should also point out that `fs` is not the only module that uses the thread pool, `dns.lookup()` (the default hostname resolution method used internally by node), async `zlib` methods, `crypto.randomBytes()`, and a couple of other things IIRC also use the libuv thread pool. This is just something to keep in mind.

Comment: I added process.env.UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE=64; and it was slower, maybe I'm not understanding your suggestion?

Comment: The libuv thread pool isn't the only potential bottleneck, there are also other things to consider like the type of storage device, any OS/filesystem-related configuration, unoptimized application logic, etc. Also setting the thread pool size to something that high probably isn't that beneficial. The default of 4 was chosen mostly to match the number of cores available on most modern processors.

Answer (score 0):

If you read many files (checkLinks) in a loop, firstly ALL the `fs.readFile` functions will be called. And only AFTER that callbacks will be processed (they processed only if main function stack is empty). This would lead to significant starting delay. But don't worry about that.

You point that a program never ends. So, make a counter, count calls to `checkLinks`, and decrease the counter after callback function is called. Inside the callback, check the counter against 0 and then do finalizing logic (I suspect this could be a response to the http request).

Actually, it doesn't matter whether you use async version or sync. They will work relatively the same time.

Comment: so ALL of fs.readFile's callbacks are paused until the last fs.readFile call is called?

Comment: Yes. That's right. You can see this if you log my suggested counter.